# ConnectionFailure while connecting to mongoDB from external script

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I created a Ruby app on OpenShift, I added mongodb cartridge and my app starts every hour and gets some data from a RSS feed and pushes it onto a mongo collection. Now, I want to get data from mongo with another script.

My code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/qJAhiXfb

When I try to run this script from my computer in terminal as `ruby getData.rb` I get this error message:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mongo-1.11.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:422:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at 127.3.214.130:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mongo-1.11.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:661:in `setup'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mongo-1.11.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:177:in `initialize'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mongo-1.11.1/lib/mongo/legacy.rb:52:in `initialize'
from getData.rb:7:in `new'
from getData.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I searched the internet for a solution, but I couldn't find anything!

Comment: Your script cannot connect to the mongodb instance. Do you have the right host/ip and port? Can you connect with the mongo shell?

Comment: If I run "db = connect("127.3.214.130:27017/rubyscrapper")" in mongo shell, i get this error:
connecting to: 127.3.214.130:27017/rubyscrapper
2014-11-17T20:51:15.494+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.3.214.130:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-17T20:51:15.495+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.3.214.130:27017 (127.3.214.130), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148

The host is correct. My ruby script from the server can "speak" with mongo via this host and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I solved this problem using `rhc` to create a tunnel for communication between my local machine and openshift aplication. All you need to do for opening tunnel you just need to run `rhc port-forward APP_NAME` and this will bind some ports and starts communication  between local machine and the server.